# I can't start the activity or fragment from main activity via FAB

Tags: android, kotlin

I was generated new activity + fragment named "adddebtinfo"

[image]
and try to start this activity using FAB in MainActivity but it doesn't work at all.

MainActivity.kt

```
    var fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, AddDebtInfoFragment::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
```

AddDebtInfoFragment.kt

```
private lateinit var viewModel: AddDebtInfoViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    var binding : AddDebtInfoActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater ,R.layout.add_debt_info_fragment,container , false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AddDebtInfoViewModel::class.java)
    // TODO: Use the ViewModel
}
```

}

add_debt_info_fragment.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_debt_info_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.adddebtinfo.AddDebtInfoFragment">
```

add_debt_info_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".AddDebtInfo"/>
```

Comment: Are you really going to start Fragment by Intent?

Comment: not really, but i'm so confuse with it.

Comment: You should launch your activity which is host for fragment. Only components can receive intent. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start a Fragment using Intent. You should replace the `AddDebtInfoFragment` with the name of the activity in the following line:
`val intent = Intent(this, AddDebtInfoFragment::class.java)`

Answer (score 0):

For add / replace fragment you need to perform FragmentTrascations on click of the FAB.
For open a new activity you need to perform `startActivity(someIntent)` with respect to FAB's activity / context.

Answer (score 0):

Purusann, you want to use `FragmentTransaction` with the container `FrameLayout` you have.

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
   // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        val firstFragment = AddDebtInfoFragment()

        // Add the fragment to the 'container' FrameLayout
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, firstFragment).commit()
}
```

Please read this Android doc page to understand how to use Fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui